# Using substring function in groupby of NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, core-data

As I am new in Core-Data, I would like to have a equivalent of following SQL query in form of Core-Data expressions.

> SELECT Date,SUM(Amount) FROM Transactions GROUP BY
>   SUBSTRING(Date,0,7);

I have wrote the following codes which does approximately what I have described before, except for the **substring** part of **group by** switch.

```
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"amount"];
NSExpression *sumOfAmountExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

NSExpressionDescription *sumOfAmountField = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[sumOfAmountField setName:@"sumOfAmount"];
[sumOfAmountField setExpression:sumOfAmountExpression];
[sumOfAmountField setExpressionResultType:NSDoubleAttributeType];

[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"date", nil]];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sumOfAmountField, @"date", nil]];
```

Does any one know how edit the code to have the similar result as the SQL query?